# Undefined method 'pluralize' for #<Controller>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pluralize, undefined-function

Not sure why this has decided to stop working.

**customers_controller.rb**

```
redirect_to customers_url,
            notice: pluralize(@imported_customers.size, "customer") + " imported!"
```

And I'm getting the error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method 'pluralize' for #CustomersController:0x007f3ca8378a20

Any idea where to start looking?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you don't want to use view helpers, then you can use `String#pluralize`:

```
"customer".pluralize(@imported_customers.size)
```

If you want to use view helpers then you should include the respective helper as another answers or just use `ActionView::Rendering#view_context`:

```
view_context.pluralize(@imported_customers.size, "customer")
```

Comment: Aha! I didn't realize `String` had a pluralize method. I chose this answer because it doesn't involve me bringing view helpers into the controller. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth being clear that this is not a native Ruby method, rather `String#pluralize` is a method that Rails monkeypatches onto the `String` class.

Comment: Also worth noting that unlike `pluralize`, using `"Customer".pluralize` will not return the number as well as the String. `pluralize( 2, "Customer" )` returns "2 Customers" where as `"Customer".pluralize( 2 )` returns "Customers".

Answer (score 14):

By default, the `pluralize` method is only made available in your views. To use it in a controller, put this at the top of your controller class:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

like

```
# app/controllers/cutomers_controller.rb

class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

  def index
  etc. ...
```

Comment: This answer is correct, however, I'd prefer not to have to load the view helpers into the controller. You do provide a good explanation though, so +1

Comment: I agree that the other answers are better. :)

Answer (score 14):

You can call pluralize helper with:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.pluralize(@imported_customers.size, "customer") + " imported!"
```

or

```
# app/controllers/cutomers_controller.rb

class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

Comment: This (these) should work in any context (in or out of Controllers) in Rails and so is useful.